# Set MySQL Timestamp field using Faker

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, faker

I can't seem to get a timestamp in a format that my database seeder will accept.

I am running this command in `php artisan tinker`:

```
$faker->dateTimeThisYear($max = '+1 year')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Which produces:

```
"2015-03-17 01:26:44"
```

As far as I can tell, this matches the format that the database expects (`0000-00-00 00:00:00`). However, when I try to seed the DB I get the following errors:

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]                
  The separation symbol could not be found  
  Unexpected data found.                    
  Hour can not be higher than 12            
  Unexpected data found.                    
  A meridian could not be found
```

Every other variation I've tried including passing an actual DateTime object has not worked either. Not even this format: `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'`

This doesn't work either:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2000-05-05 22:22:22')
```

Error:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given
```

**Most disturbingly** is that in the migrations for that column, I can specify `Carbon::now()` as the default value and it works with no problem. It's only when seeding that these errors crop up. It won't even let me use `Carbon::now()` when seeding.

**Migration:**

```
$table->timestamp('time_available')->default(Carbon::now());
```

**Seeding:**

```
$factory->define(App\AvailableMeeting::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
return [
    'office_id' => 1,
    'worker_id' => 1,
    'length_minutes' => $faker->numberBetween(14,61),
    'time_available' => $faker->dateTimeThisYear('+1 year')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') // doesn't work.. neither does Carbon::now()
    ];
});
```

**Database:**

[image: database]

Your thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the actual seeder code that sets the date, please, if that's where the error is coming from? (Also, when you say it won't "let" you use Carbon::now when seeding, what's the error you get?)

Comment: Hey @MattGibson, I have updated the question. When I use `Carbon::now()` while seeding I get....  [InvalidArgumentException]                
  The separation symbol could not be found  
  Unexpected data found.                    
  Unexpected data found.                    
  Unexpected data found.                    
  A meridian could not be found

Comment: (Also, can you post the database definition for the table you're trying to insert into? Bear in mind you might find this your problem is actually coming from a different field, if, for example, you've accidentally defined one of the other columns as a date type and are now trying to insert the wrong kind of value into it...)

Comment: @MattGibson All the info should be there now. Thank you !